# android app is slow with 2,500 imageview

Tags: android

I tried to create my game with 2,500 images in table layout by code in runtime (one image is a dot of game), and everything is ok but only in onTouch event, it is very slow to response, when i touching it is take about 3 seconds to response, and i tried to test by put a runable with loop is 20 milisecond and when run it is seem take 1 second to loop.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.imgTouch) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = event.getX();
                y1 = event.getY();
                txtTest.setText("" + x1+"/"+img[10][10].getDrawable().toString());
                break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             break;
    }
}
    return true;
}

private void LoadScreen() {
    int w = (int) (screenWidth / mCols-0.75);
    ImageView view;
    for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int j = 0; j < mCols; j++) {
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(w, w);
            lp.setMargins(0,1, 1, 0);
            view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            view.setLayoutParams(lp);

            if (j==mCols-1 || i==mRows-1 || j==0 ||i==0)
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            else
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220,225,219));

             view.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
            tr.addView(view);
            img[i][j]=view;
        }
        tblScreen.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all images in table are visible all the time? or is it visible when it scrolled to its position?

Comment: when run this game will be liked: https://www.flickr.com/photos/itismyaccount/24341123950/in/dateposted-public/, and for each imageview that background color will changed form white to black or else.

Answer (score 1):

Views are complicated objects that contain a lot of state and execute non-trivial amounts of code at critical times, primarily on the UI thread. When Android wants to display your UI, it needs to traverse the entire view hierarchy to (a) measure, (b) layout, and (c) draw those views. A change to any view can cause Android to re-run any or all of these traversals. Additionally, there are other traversals that must happen in various situations, such as propagating touch events.

I cannot think of any situation where you should have 2500 `ImageView`s in your view hierarchy (as well as whatever container views you are using to arrange those `ImageView`s). Clearly it is taking entirely too long for Android to process UI events over such a hierarchy, resulting in delayed response to input events and skipping draw frames.

I don't know your specific use case, but you should be doing either of the following:

- If only a subset of your "dots" are visible on screen at any given time, use some kind of `View` recycling so that only the views you need to display are in the view hierarchy. This is exactly what classes like `ListView` and `RecyclerView` are for: they contain enough views to display what will fit on screen, and they will recycle views that get scrolled off the screen as new items need to be scrolled onto the screen.
- If all of your "dots" are on screen all the time, try writing a subclass of `View` to do your own custom drawing. You don't need one `ImageView` per dot which keeps the state of its dot, you just need a `View` that knows how to draw dots. You can keep the state of all your dots in whatever efficient data structure you like and have the one view draw all of them.

Consider how both of those options cuts down the size (and the depth) of your view hierarchy and what effect that will have when Android needs to traverse it.

Comment: Thank for your help, so i think i use canvas to draw 2,500 shapes type rectangle which background color is white, and re-draw rectangle which background color is black to change status of dot. And i also think load 2,500 imageview at one time is not feasibility.